# Invalid credentials error message on Compute Engine and Container Engine but not App Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created a Google Cloud account, upgraded it from the free account, created a project. I'm an owner of the project. I've deployed to the project using App Engine. In the web console, when I click on App Engine I see the App Engine console. When I click on Compute Engine or Container Engine I get an error message "Invalid Credentials" with no explanation. IAM shows me as a project owner. Any ideas what this error might mean and how I might resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with cookies. Deleting the related cookies resolved the issue.

Comment: How you delete them?